# Agregar valores automáticamente en lista de Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy tratando de generar un programa en el cual con base a un archivo csv con diferentes registros los cuales tienen listas con 3 valores cada una del rango del 1 al 30 con orden aleatorio.
Quiero generar con un loop diferentes listas en un rango del 1 al 30 igualmente con solo 3 valores y que con el loop se generen automáticamente listas que no sean iguales a las ya existentes en el archivo csv para al final poder tener más combinaciones de números.
Les dejo una parte del código que he logrado generar pero el problema es que las nuevas listas las estoy creando manualmente.
Me ayudarían bastante, muchas muchas gracias.

```
import csv  //Se importa csv
listaNueva = [] //Lista donde se almacenarán los nuevos valores
//Inicia código para crear una lista con base al archivo csv

with open("ArchivoLista.csv", "r", newline='') as f:  
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")  
next(reader)  
res = [[int(n) for n in line[:]] for line in reader]  

for iter in res:    
  print(iter)
 //Termina codigo para crear listas con los registros del csv


 //Ingreso manualmente los 3 numeros que contendra la lista a generar
 for lista in range(3):  
  valor = int(input("Ingresa el valor: "))  
  listaNueva.append(valor)    

//Se comparan las listas, si los numeros ingresados no estaban en el csv
//se imprime "No son iguales"
if listaNueva in res:  
  print("Los valores de la lista son iguales", iter, "", listaNueva)  
else:  
  print("No son iguales")
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar un generador de números aleatorios, por ejemplo, los que proporciona la biblioteca numpy.

```
import numpy as np

 for lista in range(3):  
  valor = np.random.randint(0, 101) #generamos un int aleatorio entre 0 y 100
  listaNueva.append(valor)
```

Mis valores 0 y 100 son de ejemplo, puedes poner lo que tú quieras.

Comment: Con randint(0, 100) generarías un aleatorio entre 0 y 99, debería ser randint(0, 101). Por otro lado, puedes reducir todo a lo siguiente (por si quieres incluirselo): print(list(np.random.randint(101, size=3)))

Comment: Tienes razón se me ha colado! Gracias he corregido la pregunta. La quedo simplemente con tu corrección, para que pueda ver también tú  aporte con el comentario y tú respuesta debajo!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Antes de nada, en `python` los comentarios se indican con `#`, y tienes algunas líneas mal indentadas en tu código (imagino que ha sido al copiarlas aquí).

Si lo que quieres es obtener es las combinaciones de números posibles, igual puedes utilizar el modulo itertools que aunque lo que te devuelve son tuplas, te podría servir. Te pongo unos ejemplos:

Antes de nada, importas el módulo

```
import itertools
```

Para que veas que hace cada método (según lo que necesites), te pongo un ejemplo con un rango de 4 números:

En este primer caso cada combinación de números independientemente del orden, solo aparecerá una vez en la lista.

```
print(list(itertools.combinations(range(4), 3)))

# Devuelve 4 elementos [(0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3), (0, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
```

En este segundo caso cada combinación de números aparecerá más veces aunque en distinto orden, nunca en el mismo, pero cada número solo aparecerá una vez en cada tupla.

```
print(list(itertools.permutations(range(4), 3)))

# Devuelve 24 elementos [(0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3), (0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 3), (0, 3, 1), (0, 3, 2), (1, 0, 2), (1, 0, 3), (1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 0), (1, 3, 2), (2, 0, 1), (2, 0, 3), (2, 1, 0), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 0), (2, 3, 1), (3, 0, 1), (3, 0, 2), (3, 1, 0), (3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 0), (3, 2, 1)]
```

En este tercer caso además de aparecer los mismos números en las tuplas en distinto orden, dentro de una tupla se pueden repetir los números.

```
print(list(itertools.product(range(4), repeat=3)))

# Devuelve 64 elementos [(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 3), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3), (0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 2), (0, 2, 3), (0, 3, 0), (0, 3, 1), (0, 3, 2), (0, 3, 3), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 0, 3), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3), (1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 0), (1, 3, 1), (1, 3, 2), (1, 3, 3), (2, 0, 0), (2, 0, 1), (2, 0, 2), (2, 0, 3), (2, 1, 0), (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 2, 0), (2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 3), (2, 3, 0), (2, 3, 1), (2, 3, 2), (2, 3, 3), (3, 0, 0), (3, 0, 1), (3, 0, 2), (3, 0, 3), (3, 1, 0), (3, 1, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 1, 3), (3, 2, 0), (3, 2, 1), (3, 2, 2), (3, 2, 3), (3, 3, 0), (3, 3, 1), (3, 3, 2), (3, 3, 3)]
```

En tu caso tendrías que utilizar un `range(31)` para que te tomase valores entre 0 y 30.

Si luego quieres utilizar algún valor de forma aleatoria, puedes utilizar el módulo random (si por ejemplo te sirviese `permutations`):

```
import random

lista = list(itertools.permutations(range(4), 3)) 
print(random.choice(lista))
```